# MySQL insert computed value

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this, with a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `acl_object_identity`, `ace_order` pair.

```
+----+---------------------+-----------+
| id | acl_object_identity | ace_order |
+----+---------------------+-----------+
|  1 |                 233 |         0 |
|  2 |                 233 |         1 |
|  4 |                 233 |         2 |
|  3 |                 234 |         0 |
+----+---------------------+-----------+
```

For any given `acl_object_identity`, `ace_order` must follow an incrementing pattern. In the example above, if I insert another row with `acl_object_identity = 233`, its `ace_order` should be 3.

How can I compute the next valid `ace_order` for a given `acl_object_identity` on insert? I'm looking for something like a `max_ace_order` function that I could use inside an `insert` statement:

```sql
insert into acl_entry (acl_object_identity, ace_order) values (233, max_ace_order(233) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a subquery:

```
insert into acl_entry (acl_object_identity, ace_order)
select 233, 1+(select MAX(ace_order) from acl_entry where acl_object_identity=233);
```

Comment: Thanks @golimar. In case the outer select query matches several rows of another table, it seems that MAX(ace_order) is not re-evaluated after every row insertion. So all inserted rows will have the same ace_order. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe that's related to Bill's answer. Can you edit the table in your question with those rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `select 1+max(ace_order) from acl-entry where acl_object_identity=233` solution, but this has a risk of a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). That is, two concurrent sessions try to insert a new row for object 233 at the same time, both read the same value for `max(ace_order)` and both insert the same incremented value.

To avoid this, you would have to lock the whole table first, to prevent all concurrent inserts.

```
LOCK TABLE acl_entry WRITE;
INSERT ... (as above)
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

All sessions who would insert to the table would need to do this.